# Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, rss

I am trying to get images from a RSS feed. Here is the structure of the feed:

```
<item>
<title>Title Here....</title>
<link>Link Here....</link>
<description>Description Here...</description>
<comments>Comments Here.</comments>
<pubDate>Tue, 15 Sep 2015 22:54:00 +0000</pubDate>
<guid isPermaLink="false">59551 at http://winsupersite.com</guid>
<media:thumbnail url="http://winsupersite.com/site-files/winsupersite.com/files/imagecache/thumb_img/uploads/2015/09/windowsrt81update3hero.png" />
<media:content url="http://winsupersite.com/site-files/winsupersite.com/files/uploads/2015/09/windowsrt81update3hero.png" medium="image">
</media:content>
</item>
```

This is my PHP code:

```
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load('http://winsupersite.com/rss.xml');
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
   $title = $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
   $src   = $node->getElementsByTagName('thumbnail')->item(0)->getAttribute('url');
   $link  = $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

But I get the error:

> Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object

Why am I getting this error? Both the `thumbnail` tag and the `url` attribute exist.

Here is the result of var_dump on $rss:

```
object(DOMDocument)#1 (34) { 
["doctype"]=> NULL ["implementation"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" 
["documentElement"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["actualEncoding"]=> string(5) "utf-8" 
["encoding"]=> string(5) "utf-8" ["xmlEncoding"]=> string(5) "utf-8" ["standalone"]=> bool(true) 
["xmlStandalone"]=> bool(true) ["version"]=> string(3) "1.0" ["xmlVersion"]=> string(3) "1.0" ["strictErrorChecking"]=> bool(true)        ["documentURI"]=> string(31) "http://winsupersite.com/rss.xml" 
["config"]=> NULL ["formatOutput"]=> bool(false) ["validateOnParse"]=> bool(false) 
["resolveExternals"]=> bool(false) ["preserveWhiteSpace"]=> bool(true) ["recover"]=> bool(false) ["substituteEntities"]=> bool(false) ["nodeName"]=> string(9) "#document" ["nodeValue"]=> NULL ["nodeType"]=> int(9) ["parentNode"]=> NULL 
["childNodes"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["firstChild"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["lastChild"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["previousSibling"]=> NULL ["attributes"]=> NULL 
["ownerDocument"]=> NULL ["namespaceURI"]=> NULL ["prefix"]=> string(0) "" ["localName"]=> NULL ["baseURI"]=> string(31) "http://winsupersite.com/rss.xml" ["textContent"]=> string(27278) " SuperSite for Win........ Just text after this
```

Comment: So what _is_ `$rss`? We cannot guess that, you have to tell us. Dump the variable into a log file and see. most likely creating the object simply fails. You really should starting looking into your log files. You could see what the issue is in there yourself.

Comment: $rss is a variable. This is my script from beginning there is nothing else.

Comment: I asked what the _content_ of `$rss` is. Dump it. See.

Comment: @arkascha I have updated the question now.

Comment: @SujataHulsurkar check below code it will solve your problem.

Comment: @SujataHulsurkar have you test code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You posted only a part of the XML without the namespace definitions. You should have a namespace definition like `xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"` on an ancestor node.

DOM uses the definitions to resolve the prefixes while parsing the XML. Element and attribute nodes with a prefix belong to the namespace. You can read the name like `{http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/}:thumbnail`. Namespaces allow to mix different formats with the same node names without causing conflicts.

Most of the DOM methods have two versions, the default method and a variant with the suffix 'NS' that is namespace aware.

```
$src = $node
  ->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/', 'thumbnail')
  ->item(0)
  ->getAttribute('url');
```

`DOMNode::getElementsByTagName[NS]()` always returns a node list, this list can be empty. If you access the first item of an empty list the result is an error. To make you source stable, you would need to validate that the list has an item before accessing it.

Or you could use Xpath expressions. They are more powerful an allow you to fetch node lists or scalar values from the DOM.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->load($feedUrl);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$xpath->registerNamespace('m', 'http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//item') as $item) {
  var_dump(
    [
      'title' => $xpath->evaluate('string(title)', $item),
      'src' => $xpath->evaluate('string(m:thumbnail/@url)', $item),
      'link' => $xpath->evaluate('string(link)', $item)
    ]
  );
}
```

`m:thumbnail/@url` will be fetch the `url` attribute of the `thumbnail` child node in the `http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/` namespace. `string()` will cast the node to a string, if no node was found it will return an empty string.

Comment: The first method was still showing errors but the second method with Xpath worked. Thanks. :)

Comment: The first method will throw an error if the node does not exists. On an empty node list `item(0)` will return `NULL`, `NULL` is not an object, hence the error. With Xpath the result type is defined by the expression. You can always iterate a list even if it is empty and the other expressions return scalars.

Answer (score 0):

`thumbnail` is inside the `media` namespace so you need to use [getElementsByTagNameNS](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagnamens.php) to access it.

You didn't include the full RSS document, but basically the namespace you need should be in the header, for example if it's "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/", your code will be:

```
$src = $node->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/', 'thumbnail')->item(0)->getAttribute('url');
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error. This is what I have done: `  $src         = $node->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://winsupersite.com/rss.xml','thumbnail')->item(0)->getAttribute('url');`

Answer (score 0):

Check this,

```html
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load('http://winsupersite.com/rss.xml');
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
   $title = $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
   $src   = $node->getElementsByTagName('media:thumbnail')->item(0)->getAttribute('url');
   $link  = $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

It will solve your problem.